# key algorithm in keytool of java

Tags: java, keytool, public-key-encryption

HI,

Im very new to this cryptography field .I have a small doubt regarding key algo and signature algo in using the keytool in generating public-private key pairs .I just wanna know what exactly is use of these two algorithms .

Thanks,
Bhaswanth

Answer (score 3):

You can read all about Java Crypto [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeystoreImplementation).

Answer (score 0):

A well explained article about keytool you can find at [devdaily.com blog](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-keytool-keystore-certificates). At this site you can also find more resources about java cryptography and true license library.